# merging two annotated data sets without removing any information

Tags: python, data-annotations

I have the following anndata sets

1- AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 750 × 5000
obs: 'cell_type', 'n_genes', 'species'
var: 'n_cells', 'highly_variable', 'highly_variable_rank', 'means', 'variances', 'variances_norm'
uns: 'hvg'

2- AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 750 × 5000
obs: 'cell_type', 'n_genes', 'species'
var: 'n_cells', 'highly_variable', 'highly_variable_rank', 'means', 'variances', 'variances_norm'

I tried merging them using this code

```
> merged_adata = anndata.concat(
>     [subset_frog_adata_spar_removed, subset_zebrafish_adata_spar_removed],
>     axis=0,  # Concatenate along the observation axis (axis=0)
>     join="outer",  # Use outer join to combine the variables
>     label="merged"  # Label for the merged AnnData object )
```

but merged_adata looks like this

AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1500 × 9068
obs: 'cell_type', 'n_genes', 'species', 'merged'

I am expecting/need the result to be like this

AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1500 × 10000, i.e., 10000 instead of 9068.

Could anyone help?
Thanks!